# N-Dimensional Grid Vertices Calculation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

**QUESTION: Given a cell index (red) compute the array index (black) that surround the cell index.**

```
bool CalculateCellVerticesFromIndex(size_t index, size_t* vertices)
{
    size_t gridSize[2] = {6, 5};
    return true;  // if the index was valid
    return false; // if the index was invalid
}
```

Calculate the vertices that surround a cell in a N-dimensional grid of known size (m X n X ... ).

Example diagram:

[image: 6 x 5 Grid Typo fixed]

Say `int vertices[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0}`

In the above diagram, CalculateCellVerticesFromIndex(12, vertices); should fill vertices up with {14, 15, 20, 21};

Comment: It seems you need to read about the operations of integer division and taking the remainder (modulo)

Comment: It is not for homework. It is for my job.

Comment: Hmmm, well I think that you may be right,  Sorry, my bad.  Apparently my brain is addled right now (or something).  I will remove my prior comments...

Comment: Us this C oor C++ the method signature appears C for C++ I would expect std::vector or std::array

Comment: The function signature is C-ish; but I am trying to not use std::vector for backwards compatibility with legacy code (which is C) that will have to interact with this. If you have a solution that works with std::vector or std::array I would be happy to see it too. I can translate it on my own later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Width = 6
Row = Index div (Width - 1)
if Row > 5 - 2 then OutOfGrid
Column = Index mod (Width - 1)
LeftBottom = Row * Width + Column
LeftTop = LeftBottom + Width
RightBottom and RightTop - elaborate
```

Comment: I like where this code is going, but what happens if this is a 3D grid, or even a 4D grid?

Comment: It will exploit the same principles with integer division. For example, to get layer number in 3d, it is necessary to divide Index by the product of two dimensions